# Building query from module - Best Practices

Tags: perl

I am having multiple queries that can be up to 100 or even more lines that need to be executed and I am looking for best practices / easy way to import queries from module into my main file, bind values and execute them. Exemple:

Sql.pm

```
package Sql;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw($query);

our $query = "SELECT * 
FROM ?
";
```

Main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sql;
#use DBI & connect ;

my $select = $Sql::query;
my $tbl= 'my_tbl';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($select );
$sth->execute($tbl);
```

This will give me this error:

ct_result(ct_dynamic(CS_PREPARE)) returned -205 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/DBD/Sybase.pm line 138.
DBD::Sybase::db prepare failed: Server message number=1087 severity=16 state=1 line=1 server=local text=Must declare the table variable "@P1". Server message number=8180 severity=16 state=1 line=1 server=localtext=Statement(s) could not be prepared.  at main.pl line 16.
Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at main.pl line 17.

If I do like this in my main.pl

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($select);
$sth->bind_param(1, $tbl);
$sth->execute(1);
```

I get the same error but telling me that 'Can't call method "bind_param" on an undefined value'

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a better/easy/best practice way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Define "having trouble". Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have edited the main post! Thanks for fast replies!

Comment: Your 'troubles' come from the fact that it doesn't know how to prepare your statement, hence `$sth` is undefined, and so, `$sth->...` methods will fail saying `Can't call method "..." on an undefined value`. Now from the documentation from https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values, one can see that placeholders work fine on the 'query part' for seaching values in the `WHERE` clause and when setting values for columns. BUT NOT for table names or column names, and that is what you tried to do

Comment: I understand, I have modified my code to this:  
    sql.pm 
    
    our $query = "Select * from my_tbl where col = ?";

    main.pl
     $tbl = '123'
     $sth->dbh->prepare($select) ;
     $sth->execute($tbl);

And this works, but is this a good practice? What is the best practice?

Comment: you probably want to rename your $tbl to $val

Comment: depending on the number of SQL's you have, i would see two different ways of doing it. For a few SQL's i wouldn't go through the hassle of grouping them. And what i may suggest is some solution that worked fine on reasonable large scale. But i think there are other ways of doing it... TIMTOWTDI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below is self explaining enough:

```
package My_App::Table_Name;

use feature 'state';
# save performance hit on `prepare` statements
# you said SQL statements of 100+ lines

sub sql_name {
    my $class = shift;
    my $dbh   = shift;
    my %params = @_;

    # do some checking on the params if needed, or use Type::Params::compile

    state $sth = $dbh->prepare( <<    END_OF_SQL ); # 4 spaces for neatness

        SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_foo = ? AND col_bar = ?

    END_OF_SQL

    $sth->execute(
        $params{foo},
        $params{bar},
    );
    return $sth->fetchall_hashref('id'); # or what ever
}

1;
```

And then in your app:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use My_App::Table_Name;

my $dbh = ... ; # RaiseError is your friend

my $results = My_App::Table_Name->sql_name($dbh,
    foo => 'abc',
    bar => '123',
);

# $results now contains a HashRef where the keys are the id's from the returned
# rows, each row being a HashRef itself, so you can do things like:

say $results->{42}->{col_foo};
```

This way, you can organize your SQL statements by table name, most database
modifications are acted on one table, or because of the change inside one table, causing a chain off updates elsewhere.

Inside each module, you can now create subroutines with sensible names like

```
sub create { ... };
sub delete { ... };
sub search_joined_with_table_other { ... };
```

and thus in your app:

```
My_App::Table_Name->create($dbh,
    foo => 'xyz',
    bar => '345',
);

My_App::Table_Other->delete($dbh, id => 42 );
```

And so, basically, you DO NOT care about all that SQL inside your main app, but nicely moved them away inside their own packages. And inside your app, you do not even need to know that there is SQL underneath the hood, you simply call class methods.

Next level, would be returning Row Objects for each Table_Name package and have it's own instance methods on it.

Happy coding and remember TIMTOWTDI (There is more than one way to do it)

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply and help!   
This works great, but what if I would want to use $dbh->selectall_arrayref($select, { Slice => {} });   how could I bind parameters to query $select ?

Comment: from the documentation, you can see that `$dbh->selectall_arrayref(...)` is nothing else then `$sth = $dbh->prepare(SQL_HERE); $sth->execute( params_here ); $sth->fetchall_arrayref( slice_here );` but that would defeat the `state` at the top and you would need to do internally that `prepare` over and over again ... and that ain't fun for huge SQL statements. So, my advice, split it in the three statements, rather than one compact do-it all-at-once

Comment: I would let DBI handle the statement caching via `$dbh->prepare_cached` rather than doing it in your own code.

Comment: my friend @simbabque is totally right, rolling your own is not what one should do in general. Instead of `state $sth = $dbh->prepare( ... );` one could write `my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached( ... );` ... But dragons are on your path ( see https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBI/DBI.pm#prepare_cached and the troubles it can run into ). Using `state` does avoid all those

Comment: Can't use store sth like that. Aside from tying up a resource, dbh might be different in next call.